# Keycloak +Proxy(nginx) CSP-Header Problem ({{notification.header}} {{notification.message}})

Tags: keycloak, nginx-reverse-proxy

Im currently running into some issues with the deployment of Keycloak to a Server.

The server is running behind a Nginx-Proxy. Keycloak it self is running inside a Docker-Container. Everthing works fine until i try to add CSP-Header. I still can open the default page at /auth, but when i try to enter the admin section i only get one text notification.

```
{{notification.header}} {{notification.message}}
```

[Image of the notification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yC9Qu.png)

##### Setup

- Ubuntu 20.04
- Keycloak 13.0.1

[Keyclaok Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ltpoC.png)

```
add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self'; fame-ancestors 'self'; object-src 'none' "
```

Answer (score 2):

**The CSP that you are trying to set is too tight** (`default-src 'self'` is the issue). Unfortunately Keycloak needs (at least with Version 13) some `unsafe-*` policies to work properly. I ran into the same issue.

It worked for my setup with

```
default-src 'self'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; img-src 'self'; connect-src 'self'; form-action 'self'; frame-ancestors 'self'; object-src 'none';
```

but be aware, that thanks to the `unsafe-*` entries it will not be very safe at all.

***Update for Keycloak 15.0.2***

For Keycloak 15.0.2 the `'unsafe-eval'` is no longer required! So the following CSP can be used:

```
default-src 'self'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; img-src 'self'; connect-src 'self'; form-action 'self'; frame-ancestors 'self'; object-src 'none';
```